# MySQL DB with latin1_swedish_ci collation restored show incorrect string value for column

Tags: mysql, collation

I have restored a mysql database with latin1_swedish_ci collation on to a different windows server. But connected with same application (asp.net MVC) used on older server show incorrect string value for column. There is no specific collation on the column which is showing issue.

[image: Attached is the complete char set information of source/old db]

Restored server also show same char set information.

But as I mentioned above I am getting incorrect string value.

Comment: attached image show char set information from old and new servers. Both show same settings

Comment: This might be caused by many reasons, maybe it's different mysql version caused this where a default character set is different form the new mysql server used , what I suggest it that open the sql dump and search replace character encoding to whatever fit your database.

Comment: See the following for how to furtherer diagnose the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Sorry I missed a point. Collation and char set was different when restored on new server as new server was installed with default settings. Myself corrected collation to latin1_swedish_ci and char set what I have given the table image. Any other attributes to be checked and corrected. Also any locale or other settings of Windows will create a dependency to be corrected?